# Printing in UWP app - different layout on different devices

Tags: c#, printing, uwp, windows-10-universal, printdocument

I've created printing solution for my XAML UWP MVVM application using example described on this link: https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2016/10/25/a-recipe-for-printing-in-uwp-mvvm-apps/  (The source code is on the link: https://github.com/XamlBrewer/XamlBrewer.Uwp.PrintService )

Print preview that I get on my laptop is different than the one I get on the toughbook Panasonic CF-20. On the thoughbook layout gets messed up.

On the laptop (looks exactly the same on several laptops/PCs):

[laptop_print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbckB.png)

On the thoughbook:

[thoughbook_print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnQXd.png)

My report page (page I use for preview/printing):

```
<Page
    x:Class="WK.Drf.FrontOffice.App.UI.DossierHandling.HandoverPrintReport"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WK.Drf.FrontOffice.App.UI.DossierHandling"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <RichTextBlock Height="640" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Paragraph TextAlignment="Left" Margin ="55,0,0,0">
            <Run Text="Overdracht" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <LineBreak />
        </Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">RAV Kennemerland</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AmbulanceNumber}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParamedicCode}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DriverCode}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThirdPersonCode}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" />

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PatientName}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PatientDateOfBirth}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PatientAddress1}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PatientAddress2}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" />

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PatientBsn}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PatientInsuranceCompany}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PatientInsuranceNo}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PatientEmail}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PatientPhoneNumber}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" />

                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" />
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" />

                </Grid>

            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>

        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="1" Fill="DarkGray"></Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>

        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="8" TextAlignment="Left">S</TextBlock>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding Accident, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Ongeval:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Accident}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding Accident, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding AmpleEvents, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Situatie:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AmpleEvents}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding AmpleEvents, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding AirwayS, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">A:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AirwayS}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{Binding AirwayS, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding BreathingS, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">B:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BreathingS}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Visibility="{Binding BreathingS, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding CirculationS, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">C:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CirculationS}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Visibility="{Binding CirculationS, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding DisabilityS, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">D:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisabilityS}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Visibility="{Binding DisabilityS, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding ExposureS, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">E:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ExposureS}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" Visibility="{Binding ExposureS, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                </Grid>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="1" Fill="DarkGray"></Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>

        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="6" TextAlignment="Left">B</TextBlock>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding Allergy, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Allergie:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Allergy}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding Accident, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding Medication, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Medicatie:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Medication}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding Medication, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding PastIllnesses, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Verleden ziekten:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PastIllnesses}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{Binding PastIllnesses, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding Insulation, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Isolatie:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Insulation}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Visibility="{Binding Insulation, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding InfectionRisk, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Besmettingsrisico:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding InfectionRisk}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Visibility="{Binding InfectionRisk, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                </Grid>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>

        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="1" Fill="DarkGray"></Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>

        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="8" TextAlignment="Left">A</TextBlock>

                    <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="20" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Bevindingen</TextBlock>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Hoofd en gelaat:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeadAndFace}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Nek/Hals/CWK:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Neck}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Rug:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Back}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Thorax:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Thorax}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Arm:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Arms}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Abdomen:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Abdomen}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Bekken:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Pelvis}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Been:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Legs}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="8" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Uitscheiding:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Secreteion}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="9" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Verloskundig:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Gynecology}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="10" Visibility="{Binding HeadAndFace, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                </Grid>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="20" Visibility="{Binding TreatmentSectionVisibility}">Behandeling</TextBlock>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding AirwayT, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">A:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AirwayT}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding AirwayT, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding BreathingT, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">B:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BreathingT}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{Binding BreathingT, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding CirculationT, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">C:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CirculationT}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Visibility="{Binding CirculationT, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding DisabilityT, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">D:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisabilityT}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Visibility="{Binding DisabilityT, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding ExposureT, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">E:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ExposureT}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Visibility="{Binding ExposureT, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                </Grid>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="1" Fill="DarkGray"></Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="6" TextAlignment="Left">R</TextBlock>

                    <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="20" Visibility="{Binding AdditionalExplanation, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Verklaring Geen Vervoer</TextBlock>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding AdditionalExplanation, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Reden:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AdditionalExplanation}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding AdditionalExplanation, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding AdditionalExplanationText, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}">Toelichting:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AdditionalExplanationText}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{Binding AdditionalExplanationText, Converter={StaticResource StringToVis}}"/>

                </Grid>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>

    </RichTextBlock>
</Page>
```

What should I fix to get normal looking print layout on the thoughbook?

Comment: What are the differences in layout? Width? Fonts? Pagination? Line spacing? Margins?

Comment: TextBlocks with fix text are on the same positions, but the content that I'm getting from bindings is moved - spaces between lines are much bigger, some lines are overlapped and everything is moved to the right.

Comment: It need a testing on my side, but the data is too much for me to create a  reproduce page. Could you please give me a sample record?(For example, a sample data for Airway, BreatingT, CirculationT and so on are given)?

Comment: all of them are simple strings with a lot of characters. so you can basically use the same property that returns 300 characters long random string for all of them.

Comment: I've managed to fix my solution - I've put all of the TextBlocks inside of the Border with  Padding="0" Margin="0" and now everything looks nice on the laptop and toughbook as well

Comment: <Border Padding="0" Margin="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                        <TextBlock Padding="0" Margin="0" Text="{Binding AmbulanceNumber}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                    </Border>

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix my solution - I've put all of the TextBlocks inside of the Border with Padding="0" Margin="0" and now everything looks nice on the laptop and toughbook as well:

```
<Border Padding="0" Margin="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"> 
 <TextBlock Padding="0" Margin="0" Text="{Binding AmbulanceNumber}"   
 TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/> 
</Border>
```